# How do I diff an RSS feed against last time it was run?

Tags: rss, diff

I have a feed - for example

[2011 Patents of ultraviolet screens](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/websyndication/searchFeed?DB=EPODOC&locale=en_EP&query=ultraviolet+screen+US+2011)

If I run this next week, I would like to see if there had been an update since last time I looked - are there any feed readers that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much all feed readers do this, I'd recommend Google Reader. If you were looking for a way of automating the process (like if you want a shell script to check every week), please clarify and I'll try to provide an example.

Comment: Yes please. You actually beat me to it. I used Firefox and it did not show any diff or "read" like Google reader does now I have tried it.

Comment: Firefox also has some extensions could give you the features you want.